# IndexedDB Transaction constant in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, indexeddb

the specs:

```
const unsigned short READ_ONLY = 0;
const unsigned short READ_WRITE = 1;
```

checking an `webkitIDBTransaction.__ proto __` in google chrome's console:

```
READ_ONLY: 1
READ_WRITE: 0
```

I wonder if google chrome mis-implementing the indexeddb specs here?

Comment: For anyone reading this in the future... the latest spec no longer calls for these constants to exist-- instead the strings: "readonly" and "readwrite" are to be used ... Chrome 25 removes them without warning and Firefox 17 prints a depreciation message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDBTransaction should have those properties directly, not inherit them via its prototype.

I cannot speak to previous versions but the `webkitIDBTransaction.__proto__` object doesn't have READ_WRITE or any other transaction state constants today so it's possible the object you were looking at was the wrong prototype or, as you say, its prototype (which would be what though?) was incorrectly implemented.

In any case, these constants are fine in recent builds of Chrome:

```
console.log( webkitIDBTransaction.READ_ONLY );
> 0

console.log( webkitIDBTransaction.READ_WRITE );
> 1
```